# jQuery doesn't see newly created object. How to refresh list of DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app when user clicks on button, browser creates new object. For instance:

```
$("#div1 svg").append("<ellipse id='#obj0' class='svgobjects'>");
```

It works. It appears in Chrome development tools.
Then I want to set size of my ellipse using some data.

```
if (!$(ID).length > 0) {
        console.log("Div doesn't exist");
} else {
        console.log("I found it");
}
$(ID).attr("cx", data["startX"]).attr("cy", data["startY"]).attr("rx", this.rx).attr("ry", this.ry).attr("fill", data["color"]);
```

All of these variables are OK. All of them contains correct data. But in console appears: "Div doesn't exist".

The problem is: this div IS there and have the same id as "ID" variable ("#obj0"). But in spite of all jquery sais that div doesn't exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

remove the # from the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're selecting your `ellipse` element using its ID, make sure to set it correctly with a valid value.

With CSS (and therefore with jQuery too) you would use `#obj0` to select the element having the ID `obj0`, but you don't have such element as what you have is an element with an ID defined to `#obj0`, which is an invalid value.

To solve your problem, replace the following:

```
$("#div1 svg").append("<ellipse id='#obj0' class='svgobjects'>");
```

With this:

```
$("#div1 svg").append("<ellipse id='obj0' class='svgobjects'>");
```

---

**Edit:**

In HTML5 the ID `#obj0` is actually valid (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html), but in this case you will have to select it using `$("#\#obj0")` instead of `$("#obj0")`.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using `HTML5`

```
id="#obj0" is valid ,
```

then you have to select like `$("#\#obj0")`

if you are not using `HTML5` you should `obj0` instead of `'#obj0'`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I added it to my own answer, as well as a link to the W3 ref. Cheers!